# Scrape an H1 element on the current page in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, web-scraping

I'm currently working with Wordpress. I have a hook that runs before a `<title>` attribute is populated with text that a user enters in the dashboard.

Now I want to set a default title of each page to equal an `<h1>` attribute text value on a current page. A fragment of the callback function for the hook I'm working with would look like:

```
if (!$seoTitle) {
    $seoTitle = '<....>';
}

return $seoTitle;
```

I want `seoTitle` to default to an `<h1>` element text on the current page. Is it doable? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not totally sure how you get your HTML but you could parse it with the built in DOM parser.

```
<?php

$html = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>This is a Heading one</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading two</h1>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<h1>This is a Heading three</h1>
<p><a href='testwww'> This is a paragraph.</a></p>


</body>
</html>";

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html);

//If you want to get it from a website you could do the following:
//$dom->loadHTML(file_get_contents('http://www.w3schools.com/'));

// iterate through the html to get all h1 text
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('h1') as $heading) {
    $h1 = $heading->nodeValue;
    echo $h1 . "<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: Certainly, that's the way to go. However, as I noted in my other comments, I wanted to change the `<title>` attribute of a page with PHP after a page has   been rendered - which will not be possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have your HTML content within a variable and doing this after the page has fully loaded please take a look at the below example:

```
<?php
$htmlContent = '<html><body><h1>HELLO</h1></body></html>'; // change this to what you need
$seoTitle = preg_replace('/(.*)<h1>([^>]*)<\/h1>(.*)/is', '$2', $htmlContent);
echo $seoTitle; // will output: HELLO
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "<h1>".(string)$seoTitle."</h1>";
```

Should work. You can also break out of the php `?>` and then type regular html and then break in when you wanna echo the variable.

Comment: I need to scrap the `h1` element form the current page, from the DOM. And then assign this value to `$seoTitle`, not the other way round.

Comment: You want it from the DOM? You could for instance use: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ but otherwise it's not completely clear what you want to achieve with this. Sounds like something you want to do before rendering the DOM.

Comment: @tvgemert, Actually, I'm in the wrong here. I really need to grab the `H1` before the DOM is loaded so scraping it from the DOM does not make sense. I should probably query a database or get the value from some other source, e.g. query vars if they contain what I'm looking for.